# Error Could not find or load main class -jar

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am working on a java UNO project, OS : Ubuntu 14. I am calling exec via passing command to run via a jar file with some set of sub commands of that jar file.

```
String finalOutputMSG = "";

  String[] cmd = {JAVA_LOCATION, " -jar ", JAR_LOCATION, " " + inputFile, " -dir ", ".isc", " -out xml"};//java location provides java location, jar location provides jar location, inputfile contains input file's location -dir provides output directory with name .isc, -out is output file with file format for output is xml
```

Similar command ran properly without showing any errors but in a case where I am trying to import a file and convert it into another format eg .xlsx to .xml, is giving error. In commands it worked, I have already generated outputs from an input file.

```
     finalOutputMSG = exec(cmd);

     /**
     * exec() is executed and outputs are displayed
     *
     * @param String[] command passed to jar
     * @return output message containing outputs or output message
     */      
      private static String exec(String[] cmd) {

            String outputMSG = "";

        Process proc = null;
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);//any error output generated by subprocesses merged with the standard output,
            //read using the Process.getInputStream()
///* Start the process */
            proc = pb.start();
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println("Process started !");
            }

            outputMSG = getOutput(proc);
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println("outputMSG " + outputMSG);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println("Exception in exec " + e.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception in exec ");
            }
//            StringBuilder append = appendToFile.append("Exception in exec ").append(e.getMessage());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println("Exception in exec " + e.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception in exec ");
            }
        } finally {
            ///* Clean-up */
            proc.destroy();
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println("Process ended !");
            }
        }
        return outputMSG;
    }
    /**
     * Reads output from current process
     *
     * @param current process
     * @return output read in current process
     */
    private static String getOutput(Process p) {
        StringBuilder outStream = new StringBuilder();
        if (debug) {
            System.out.println("StringBuilder initialized in getOutput");
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println("BufferedReader initialized in getOutput");
            }
            String line = null;
            if (debug) {
                System.out.println("in.readLine() in getOutput abt to be read");
            }

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outStream.append(line);
                if (debug) {
                    System.out.println("line in getOutput " + line);
                    System.out.println("outStream in getOutput " + outStream);
                }
                outStream.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (debug1) {
                System.out.println("IOException in getOutputs " + e.getMessage());
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (debug1) {
                System.out.println("Exception in getOutputs" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return outStream.toString();
    }
```

Error Message depicted by Netbeans 
Error: Could not find or load main class  -jar

I have searched on the issue, but could not find any help that is useful, I could not understand, what is missing.

Comment: What are the values of `JAVA_LOCATION` and `JAR_LOCATION`? And how are you running this? The error message means that Java thinks you are trying to run a class named `-jar`. Somewhere you are specifying the command wrong.

Comment: @Jesper /home/agnisys01/.openoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/svrgyc4k.tmp_/Cal.oxt/images/jresdir/jre_lin/bin/java -jar /home/agnisys01/.openoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/svrgyc4k.tmp_/Cal.oxt/lib/Batch.jar /home/agnisys01/Desktop/agnisys02Backup/Cal/testcases/ExcelTest1/ODStEST/fullVariant/full_variant_feature_excel.xlsx -dir /home/agnisys01/Desktop/agnisys02Backup/Cal/testcases/ExcelTest1/ODStEST/fullVariant/.ids -out xml this is sample passed, similar command is running fine for generating outputs with just -out , it's value is changed. So command is not wrong.

Comment: I used finalOutputMSG = exec(cmd); in a method to run it, stated above in the problem statement

Comment: /home/agnisys01/.openoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_pa‌​ckages/svrgyc4k.tmp_‌​/Cal.oxt/images/jres‌​dir/jre_lin/bin/java -jar /home/agnisys01/.openoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_pa‌​ckages/svrgyc4k.tmp_‌​/Cal.oxt/lib/Batch.j‌ar  /home/agnisys01/Desktop/agnisys02Backup/Cal/testcases/ExcelTest1/ODStEST/LGE_PE_CC54_RegDB.xlsx -dir /home/agnisys01/Desktop/agnisys02Backup/Cal/testcases/ExcelTest1/ODStEST/ids -out xml    This command ran just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
String[] cmd = {JAVA_LOCATION, " -jar ", JAR_LOCATION, " " + inputFile, " -dir ", ".isc", " -out xml"};
```

I replaced the values that printed in console, and ran the command so got on terminal, it worked fine.
Solution: the command to be used must be without any spaces in the ends. Because terminal in linux interprets the commands like for "ls", but in java/ any programming language, it doesn't interprets for ls, so in case of the following parameter cmdarray

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray)
             throws IOException
```

takes the command as it is.

```
String[] cmd = {JAVA_LOCATION, "-jar", JAR_LOCATION, inputFile, "-dir",  ".isc", "-out", "xml"};
```